# Is it possible to pass a city obtained from the API to the following function?

Tags: reactjs, geolocation, weather

I have the following function to retrieve the city via API which uses latitude and longitude:

```
export const GeoLocation = async () => {
    const geolocation = useGeolocation();
    const latitude = geolocation.latitude;
    const longitude = geolocation.longitude

  const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=${API_KEY}`;
  const res = await axios.get(url);
  let setCityLocation = {
   city: res.data.name,
  
  }
 console.log(setCityLocation);
 
}
```

How can I pass the recovered city name to the following statement:

`const [city, setCity] = useState('Turi');`

where instead of the city indicated 'Turi' I have to enter the geolocalized location.

I have all these features in which the city constant is called:

```
 const handleCityWeather = () => {
    getCityWeather(city)
    .then((setData) => {
      setWeather(setData);
      setIsHeartSelected(false);
      setLoading(false);

    })
    .catch((error) => {
      setError(true);
    })
  }

  const handleForeCast = (city) => {
    getCityForecast(city)
    .then((forecast) => {
      setForecast(forecast);
      setError(false);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      setError(true);
    })
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!city) {
      return;
    }
    handleCityWeather(city)
  }, [city, isError])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!city) {
      return;
    }
    handleForeCast(city)
  }, [city, isError])

  const debouncedSearchTerm = useDebounce((value) => setCity(value), delay);

  const onInputChange = (value) => debouncedSearchTerm(value);

  const getSearchWeather = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    getCityWeather(city);
    getCityForecast(city); 
  }
```

What value should I change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the following state:

`const [city, setCity] = useState('Turi');`

All you need to do to update the value of `city` is call `setCity`, like so:

`setCity(setCityLocation)`

Your code might look something like this:

```js
const [city, setCity] = useState('Turi');

export const GeoLocation = async () => {
    const geolocation = useGeolocation();
    const latitude = geolocation.latitude;
    const longitude = geolocation.longitude

    const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=${API_KEY}`;
    const res = await axios.get(url);
    let setCityLocation = {
        city: res.data.name,
    }
    
    // This function updates the value of city
    setCity(setCityLocation);
}
```